# phpUnit Test Report Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpunit

I am having an error while I was trying to setup phpUnit Test report from [this site](http://mattmueller.me/blog/phpunit-test-report-unit-testing-in-the-browser). I did what was asked and added index to test folder but it is showing error. Everything is working fine when I execute the same from terminal. This is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Please help me out here.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. The screenshot is not from the terminal, 2. What version of phpunit are you running?

Comment: yeah the screenshot shows the error displayed when i try to run it in browser.
The version I am using is 3.6.10.